# Change the Sort order of Devices in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, mount, devices, sort

I have Three Windows drive,

my nautilus shows devices in following order

[image]

I want it to be sorted like windows 7 does

1. C drive
2. D drive
3. E Drive
4. My Massport
5. 13 GB FS
6. Future attached removable mediums....
7. List item

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ooopsie

restarted the PC and it is now sorted in the order i desire

Comment: Please click the tick mark to close the question.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the order of the drives is chosen automatically, usually based on when they are detected/mounted. I don't think you will be able to change their order manually.